# Use functions of a class by after including third class

Tags: uml

Sorry for the naming of the title because I don't know how to name this situation.
There are three classes A, B and C. Class A need the function of class C. Class B is an instance collection of class C. So the operation should be class A calls the static method of class B to get the instance of class C.

```
//in class A 
Class C = B.getCInstance("[instance name]")
C.doSth();
```

Then what is the relationship between class A, B and C in UML? When I draw a UML class diagram, should I need to build all of the relationship between A, B and C? for example:

1. A class A uses a class B.
2. A class B has A class C.
3. A class A has A class C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the definition of the UML Usage dependency, I would say that class A uses both Class B and C and Class B uses Class C as depicted below [image]

> A Usage is a Dependency in which one NamedElement requires another NamedElement (or set of NamedElements) for its full 
>   implementation or operation. The Usage does not specify how the client uses the supplier other than the fact that the supplier is used 
>   by the definition or implementation of the client.